# postgres database setup for dev staging production enviroment

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, postgresql

I'm deploying an App using PHP (CodeIgniter framework) and postgres (i'll probably use some javascript on the client side).

I'm using a Git repository with the dev-staging-production branches, and I'd like to know what is the best way to implement the databases with postgres.

Should I create three tables for each with a prefix ie dev_, sta_, prod_? should I synchronize some tables, and how should i sync them...

Comment: In a feature branch, I commit a script of database changes (row insertions, row deletions, new tables, table changes and table drops), so these can be played back on the master branch when deploying. In theory it is a good idea to have a "reverse" script as well, so that if you need to back out of a particular deployment, you can do so quickly to minimise disruption. Some ORMs (e.g. Propel) have migration systems built-in; they might be worth looking at.

Comment: Do you need separate branches for staging/production, btw? I just use master (for staging and live) and feature branches (for ongoing work). This gives rise to four environments: local (uncommitted), branch, staging (master) and live (master). This prevents a merge problem to live causing a problem that was not detected in staging.

Comment: I'm just making tests with these three branches because I learned it in a mooc. I still don't know the best way to implement the git structure.
Your approach means to have two folders on the server, one with the staging and the other with the live, right?

Comment: Yes, they would both point to the same repo. For example you could have the repo on the same machine, and then each of staging and live would be a `file://` remote to that repo. Your deployment process would push to the repo (on the master branch) and then pull inside each of staging and live (with a `submodule update` if appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple tables I'd either go with a) multiple schemas or b) multiple databases. The latter option is preferrable since this allows you to run dev and staging databases on other hosts than the productions database.

In principle you would then manage your data in the production database only and sync them to the staging and dev database regularly or on demand, e.g. with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

*halfer*'s comment on managing schema changes is a good approach.